# When solving 13 equation linear equation takes too much, does it mean some problem of specification?

Tags: python

I am solving 13 linear equation and 13  unknown variables in python. I am using the sympy.

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
```

Instead of number in front of variales , I have paramaters. For example:

```
X=a*y+b
y=d*x+k
```

where X and y are unknown variables, and a, b,d, and k are parameters. I want finally solution x and y expressed in terms of parameters. I am using this kind of code:(I have 13 equation instead)

```
x, y,a,b,c,d,k = symbols('x, y,a,b,c,d,k') 
eq1 = Eq((a*y+b), x)
eq2 = Eq((d*x+k),y) 
print(solve((eq1, eq2), (x, y)))
```

Solving the equations takes too much time(it is running 4 hours, and is not finished yet). Does it mean it has some problem?

Comment: Walk before you run.  Can you try an equation with 3 variables?  5?  And so on.  How long does each take?

Comment: You want to solve these in terms of the parameters? Why don't you start with a smaller probem?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with sympy, but in your line `eq1 = Eq((a*y+b), x)`, shouldn't that be: `eq1 = Eq((x=a*y+b), x)` ? It seems to have a different formulation to your second equation where you do include the `y=` part anyway,

Comment: @ThomasKimber I fixed it here. I wrote it the wrong way